# Nikon D70, can I use manual aperture ring without getting the FEE error?

Tags: aperture, old-lenses, manual-mode, error, nikon-d70

I'm trying to use a Nikkor AF 35-105 zoom lens on a Nikon D70, and if I try to move the aperture ring from the minimum (f/22) I get the FEE error.

Now, I seem to understand that it means that the camera has to control the aperture and to do so I have to lock the ring at the minimum. But can I still somehow use the aperture ring or am I forced to use the in-camera settings?

Comment: Have you checked the manual?  IIRC you might be ok in `Manual` mode but otherwise you control all settings via the command dials, that's what they're for...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @KaushikGhose well I just got the camera, and I was playing with it. Since I also have a prime lens with a D5100 and I can only control the aperture via the mechanical ring, I was wondering why I couldn't control it in this. I also thought that using the ring would be more intuitive, but actually it's nicer to have it under control from the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this.
Switch your camera to Manual mode, and it should work. 
If it still shows FEE, you will need to trick the camera into thinking its a non-cpu lens, you can do this by applying a bit of tape over the contacts on the lens before attaching it.

HOWEVER:
You now have to set aperture and shutter speed manually, aditionally auto focus may not work on some lenses.

ALso note, you will suffer difficulty auto-focusing at apertures smaller than f8.

Comment: Mh, I think it's not worth it then :)